# Opencv c++. Draw a circle on different pixel of image in a for loop, (the image should be open new at each loop run)

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to plot circles on a image where each previous circle is deleted on the image before the next circle is drawn.

I have to following configuration:

1. I have several picture (let says 10)
2. For each picture I test several pixel for some condition (let say 50 pixels).
3. For each pixel I'm testing (or working on) I want to draw a circle at that pixel for visualization purpose (for me to visualize that pixel).
4. To summarize I have 2 for loop, one looping over the 10 images and the other looping over the 50 pixels.

I done the following (see code above). The circles are correctly drawn but when the next circle is drawn, the previous circle is still visible (at the end all circle are drawn on the same image) but what I want to have is (after a circle was drawn) to close the picture (or window) somehow and reopen a new one and plot the next circle on it and so on

```
for(int imgID=0; imgID < numbImgs; imgID++)
{
cv::Mat colorImg = imgVector[imgID]; 
for(int pixelID=0; pixelID < numPixelsToBeTested; pixelID++)
{
some_pixel = ... //some pixel 
x = some_pixel(0); y = some_pixel(1); 
cv::Mat colorImg2 = colorImg; //redefine the image for each pixel
cv::circle(colorImg2, cv::Point(x,y),5, cv::Scalar(0,0,255),1, cv::LINE_8, 0);
// creating a new window each time
cv::namedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  
cv::imshow("Display", colorImg2);                           
cv::waitKey(0);
cv::destroyWindow("Display");
}
}
```

What is wrong in my code? 
Thanks guys

Comment: Hi there, 
One thing that OpenCV aims to do is to reduce unnecessary copying of image data.  I'd double-check that the images in your imgVector are not all pointing to the same object beneath the hood.
If you want two separate images you have to create the second one using the first as the source.  Just creating a new cv::Mat 'pointer' doesn't ensure you have a new image object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::circle()` manipulates the input image within the API call, so what you need to do is to create a clone of the original image, draw circles on the cloned image and at each iteration swap the cloned image with original image.

It is also a good idea to break your program into smaller methods, making the code more readable and easy to understand, Following code may give you a starting point.

```
void visualizePoints(cv::Mat mat) {
    cv::Mat debugMat = mat.clone();

    // Dummy set of points, to be replace with the 50 points youo are using.
    std::vector<cv::Point> points = {cv::Point(30, 30), cv::Point(30, 100), cv::Point(100, 30), cv::Point(100, 100)};
    for (cv::Point p:points) {
        cv::circle(debugMat, p, 5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, cv::LINE_8, 0);

        cv::imshow("Display", debugMat);
        cv::waitKey(800);
        debugMat = mat.clone();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> imagePaths = {"path/img1.png", "path/img2.png", "path/img3.png"};
    cv::namedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    for (std::string path:imagePaths) {
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path);
        visualizePoints(img);
    }
}
```